# Associate values in different list

Tags: excel

I have a list with 3300 names and address. The unique names are just 300. In order to geocode them, I've searched just for the unique address, obtaining the coordinates for each address.

Now I have this two list in two MS excel's sheets and I'd like to associate each name with the coordinates of his address.

[image: i.imgur.com/hmaLgCD.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding the `Latitude` and `Longitude` columns into your blue table instead of creating the green one.

Use following formulas:

```
=INDEX(Latitude_orange_column, MATCH(address1_blue_cell, Address_orange_column, 0))
=INDEX(Longitude_orange_column, MATCH(address1_blue_cell, Address_orange_column, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a VBA version which allows you the flexibility to (1) customise for your worksheet names and the location(s) of your starting data and (2) put your 'results' into any sheet at any starting cell position.

Essentially, the code puts your data into arrays, processes it and puts the results into a third array.  It is then easy to transfer this 'results' array to a specified range on a specified worksheet.

**Note: Run the code on a copy of your data because it removes duplicates from your Names data.**

```
Option Explicit
Sub AssocLocs()
Dim wsName As Worksheet, wsLocn As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
Dim nmeRng As Range, locnRng As Range
Dim nmeStRow As Long, nmeEndRow As Long, nmeCol As Long
Dim locnStRow As Long, locnEndRow As Long, locnCol As Long
Dim resStRow As Long, resCol As Long
Dim N As Long, L As Long, e As Long
Dim nmeArr(), locnArr(), resArr()

'Setup======================================
    'worksheets
    Set wsName = Sheets("Sheet1")   'name data
    Set wsLocn = Sheets("Sheet2")   'location data
    Set wsRes = Sheets("Sheet1")    'results
    'original data (x2) cell start positions
    nmeStRow = 2    'header row
    nmeCol = 2
    locnStRow = 2   'header row
    locnCol = 2
    'result destination cell start position
    resStRow = 2
    resCol = 6
'===========================================

    'unique name data into array
    With wsName
        nmeEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, nmeCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set nmeRng = .Range(.Cells(nmeStRow + 1, nmeCol), .Cells(nmeEndRow, nmeCol + 1))
        nmeRng.Sort Key1:=.Range("B3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        nmeRng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1 ', Header:=xlYes
        nmeEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, nmeCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set nmeRng = .Range(.Cells(nmeStRow + 1, nmeCol), .Cells(nmeEndRow, nmeCol + 1))
        nmeArr() = nmeRng.Value
    End With

    'sorted location data into array
    With wsLocn
        locnEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, locnCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set locnRng = .Range(.Cells(locnStRow, locnCol), .Cells(locnEndRow, locnCol + 2))
        locnRng.Sort Key1:=.Range("B3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        locnArr() = locnRng.Value
    End With

e = -1

    For N = LBound(nmeArr()) To UBound(nmeArr())
        For L = LBound(locnArr()) To UBound(locnArr())
            If nmeArr(N, 2) = locnArr(L, 1) Then
                e = e + 1
                ReDim Preserve resArr(4, e)
                resArr(0, e) = nmeArr(N, 1)
                resArr(1, e) = nmeArr(N, 2)
                resArr(2, e) = locnArr(L, 2)
                resArr(3, e) = locnArr(L, 3)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next L
    Next N

    With wsRes
        .Range(.Cells(resStRow, resCol), .Cells(resStRow + UBound(resArr, 2), resCol + 4)) = Application.Transpose(resArr)
    End With

End Sub
```

Finally, [this article](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/07/03/find-matching-data-in-array-speed-test/) is quite a good read which vindicates the use of loops to iterate an array.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, barryleajio. Btw I found the method of Aprillion more suitable for my problem.

Comment: That's great - glad you're sorted and thank you for the courtesy and feedback.